# Efficient way to count number of objects with certain characteristics in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Please edit the title if you can think of a way to improve it.

---

I have a table that contains dozens of rows now, but will have hundreds in production and possibly thousands eventually. I need to count how many have certain characteristics, for example having an enum property set to a target enum.

For the sake of the question, we'll say I have in my model:

```
public enum Types { One, Two, Three, Four }
public Types Type = Types.One; // Or Two, etc.
```

Currently, each time the index page -- which lists these entries -- is accessed, I enumerate(?) counters for `One, Two, Three, Four` and display them at the top of the page.

Current method:
- Loop through every object in the table, check its properties, and increment relevant counter(s) -- each time the list is loaded

Potential methods:
- Is LINQ any faster? i.e. db.MySet.Where(obj => obj.Type == Model.Types.One)
- Could I keep these counters in memory at all times? Not sure how to do that. If that's possible, a potential solution would be adding to these counters in the `MyModelController.Create` method.

Comment: I would be tempted to use a completely different approach.  I would use triggers on the database table to update values in a separate "counter" table.  Then all I need to do is read the column headings from the counter table, being careful to refresh on any change to the main table.  The triggers will simply be doing CountA = CountA + 1 or CountB = CountB -1, which will be much, much faster than re-counting the whole table every time.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Here I am wondering how to use persistent data, when I have a database sitting in front of me... I don't know how to capture database changes any more gracefully than `Controller.Create`, but I suppose that would do it. Any potential sync issues here? Not sure why there would be, in particular, but doing it that way makes me concerned about potentially missing an increment cycle and having a permanently incorrect counter.

Comment: If your triggers are correct (and they really would not be difficult) and the initial values are correct, then they will keep perfectly in line. If you are feeling particularly paranoid, you could always run a periodic check for peace of mind - it would still be preferable to counting all on every change.

Comment: The whole point of using triggers is to get the database to trap the changes for you!

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I'm teaching myself all this as I go... I have no clue where/what these triggers are...

Comment: If you are using Entity-Framework, I'm guessing your database is SQL Server?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock That's correct. This comment thread is just begging to come and get cleaned up by a moderator -- care to move it to chat? I lack the permission. I *think* a public link can be put here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148533/discussion-between-jonathan-willcock-and-sinjai).

Answer (score 1):

> Potential methods:
>   - Is LINQ any faster? i.e. db.MySet.Where(obj => obj.Type == Model.Types.One)

LINQ would be much much better and faster. Actually all work would do SQL Server - not your application and SQL Server is optimized for such tasks. And better LINQ-code for counting objects is `db.MySet.Count(obj => obj.Type == Model.Types.One)`

> - Could I keep these counters in memory at all times? Not sure how to do that. If that's possible, a potential solution would be adding to
>     these counters in the MyModelController.Create method.

I am not sure what you mean, but you **cannot** keep something in controllers variables because controllers are created for each request and destroyed after request processing. You can persist these data in separate store but I think its unneeded complication.

Comment: What do you think about Jonathan's suggestion in the question comments? I'm inclined to agree with his suggestion: store counters in their own table, incrementing as needed. +1 for `Count()`

Comment: I think you could start with EF and LINQ because you are already familiar with this framework and because a few thousands rows are a small table size for databases and then if you saw performance issue, you could change approach to triggers.

Comment: Wouldn't I be better off still using the counter approach, even if I were to avoid SQL Server triggers? Add an EF entity that has `int` properties, and increment its values in the `ModelBinder`?

Comment: No, LINQ approach would work faster, incrementing value in the `ModelBinder` would be a cause of concurrency issue.

Comment: Okay, but say I use Jonathan's triggers suggestion. I find it hard to believe the performance difference between using database triggers and counting them all each time is negligible.